# JMeter test integration with CircleCI

Tags: jmeter, circleci

I have a testplan developed in JMeter and available in GitHub repo as .jmx file. I have integrated it with CircleCI to run it in continuous integration but the issue I am facing is that it doesn't open testplan using command (line as CircleCI uses Ubuntu as platform).

The command I am using is:

`apache-jmeter-3.2/bin/jmeter -n -t /testplan/UBO8_PerformanceTest.jmx`

The message I get in logs is:

`Could not open test UBO8_PerformanceTest.jmx`

This runs fine on local Ubuntu.

Any pointers are much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: hi, can you please let me know "I have integrated it with CircleCI to run it in continuous integration" -how to integrate it?   I have already created a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52940735/automating-jmx-files-in-circleci

Answer (score 1):

After some research on Google and by error and trial I managed to fix this. I just removed '/' from start of testplan path:

`apache-jmeter-3.2/bin/jmeter -n -t testplan/UBO8_PerformanceTest.jmx`

Testplan is running smoothly on CircleCI now.