# Automating jmx files in CircleCI

Tags: jmeter, jmx, circleci

I have couple of jmx files which I recorded and downloaded using blazemeter plugin.

I would like to know

1. How Can I integrate to CircleCI?
2. How can I set it to run daily?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. When you add a CircleCI project you have a variety of languages to choose from:

   [image: CircleCI JMeter Maven]

   I would recommend going for `Maven(Java)` as [JMeter Maven Plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin) is the easiest option for setting up and using out of other [JMeter non-GUI execution options](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui).
2. Organise your project structure as follows:

   - yourproject

     - .circleci

       - [config.yml](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/getting-started/#adding-a-yml-file)
     - src

       - test

         - jmeter

           - test.jmx
     - [pom.xml](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin#add-the-plugin-to-your-project)
3. Make sure that `config.yml` file looks as follows:

   ```
   # Java Maven CircleCI 2.0 configuration file
   #
   # Check https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/language-java/ for more details
   #
   version: 2
   jobs:
     build:
       docker:
         # specify the version you desire here
         - image: circleci/openjdk:8-jdk

         # Specify service dependencies here if necessary
         # CircleCI maintains a library of pre-built images
         # documented at https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/circleci-images/
         # - image: circleci/postgres:9.4

       working_directory: ~/repo

       environment:
         # Customize the JVM maximum heap limit
         MAVEN_OPTS: -Xmx3200m

       steps:
         - checkout

         # Download and cache dependencies
         - restore_cache:
             keys:
             - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "pom.xml" }}
             # fallback to using the latest cache if no exact match is found
             - v1-dependencies-

         - run: mvn dependency:go-offline

         - save_cache:
             paths:
               - ~/.m2
             key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "pom.xml" }}

         # run tests!
         - run: mvn verify

         - store_artifacts:
             path: target/jmeter/reports
   ```
4. Make sure your `pom.xml` looks like:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
       <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
       <groupId>org.jmeter</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven</artifactId>
       <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
       <build>
           <plugins>
               <plugin>
                   <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                   <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                   <version>2.8.0</version>
                   <executions>
                       <!-- Run JMeter tests -->
                       <execution>
                           <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                           <goals>
                               <goal>jmeter</goal>
                           </goals>
                       </execution>
                       <!-- Fail build on errors in test -->
                       <execution>
                           <id>jmeter-check-results</id>
                           <goals>
                               <goal>results</goal>
                           </goals>
                           <configuration>
                               <generateReports>true</generateReports>
                           </configuration>
                       </execution>
                   </executions>
               </plugin>
           </plugins>
       </build>
   </project>
   ```

   4. That's it, now your build will be triggered on each commit:

   [image]
5. You will be able to see [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) in build artifacts

   [image]
6. [Scheduling your builds](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#schedule) is also possible via [cron](http://www.cronmaker.com/)-like expressions

Comment: What if it's a ruby/Python project? Is there more generalised way?

Comment: Thank you so much! It really helped.

Comment: What is the procedure for a Python project?