# Errors in CircleCI config.yml

Tags: job-scheduling, circleci

I am new to the circleci.
My requirement is I need to make sure that a build is triggered and executed on a particular branch(which contains a few automation scenarios).I am finding errors in circleci when pushing the config.yml(mentioned below) to the bitbucket.

Config does not conform to schema: {:workflows {:nightly {:jobs missing-required-key}}}

The .yml file is as follows:

```
version: 2

jobs:
 test_exec:
   docker:
     - image: maven:3.3-jdk-8
   steps:
     - checkout

     - run:
         name: Run test via maven
         command: mvn -Dtest=Runner test

workflows:
  version: 2

  nightly:
    triggers:
      - schedule:
          cron: "18 23 * * *"
          filters:
            branches:
              only:
                - AT-HomePage_Filters
```

Could any one help me in fixing this issue?

Comment: Can you update the title to be more descriptive of your issue? Maybe "Errors in CircleCI config.yml".

Comment: Done.Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
version: 2

jobs:
 test_exec:
   docker:
     - image: maven:3.3-jdk-8
   steps:
     - checkout

     - run:
         name: Run test via maven
         command: mvn -Dtest=Runner test

nightly:
  triggers:
    - schedule:
        cron: "18 23 * * *"
        filters:
          branches:
            only:
              - AT-HomePage_Filters
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion,AJ.

I am getting the error message below when commited and pushed the code to Bitbucket.

    #!/bin/sh -eo pipefail
    # ERROR IN CONFIG FILE:
    # [#] required key [jobs] not found

Comment: Please check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52940735/automating-jmx-files-in-circleci